# How do I find Tanaris

Tags: world-of-warcraft

How do I get to Tanaris for the rocket rescue quest.  I cannot find it on my flight map.  What is the closest destination.?

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way is to grab the portal to the *Cavern of Time* in Dalaran. The portal is located in the [Violet Citadel](https://sivation.files.wordpress.com/2015/05/mounts-dalaran-violet-citadel-outside.jpg) [*]. This will get you there. If you can't get there because of your level you can ask a mage for a portal to Dalaran. Or you do it the old fashioned way:

Take a ride, the 3 targets in the circle are in Tanaris (the others are for Alliance, so they are different for Horde players):

[image]

If you need to walk there you'll find it in the south of Kalimdor.

- Horde:
  Just go south through the Barrens.
- Alliance: Take the ship from Booty Bay (Cape of Stranglethorn) and follow the same way from the ships destination (Ratchet)
- [Where is Booty Bay?](http://vignette4.wikia.nocookie.net/wowwiki/images/f/f7/WorldMap-TheCapeofStranglethorn.jpg/revision/latest)

[image: Kalimdor]

[*] This counts for the Dalaran in Northrend. In Legion's version of Dalaran in the Broken Isles those portals will be in the center of the city.